# Grid falls apart after i give any margin or padding

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, bootstrap-grid

I am using bootstrap-grid system with `Material UI`, everything works great just a single problem and its the fact that the grid system doesn't keep its slots space after any padding or margin and instead the items go to the next row or line when there is not enough space
[**Here is an example**](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-taussig-8z2qr?fontsize=14)
As you can see in the example, each button has a grid size of 3, meaning there should be 4 button in each row, but because of just a little bit of padding and margin now there is 3 button in each line.
What i am expecting is that the items automatically grow smaller in width when margin and padding is applied instead of going to the next line or row, how can i achieve such a thing ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the bootstrap col- classes on your button. Wrap your button inside a div like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    buttonArray.push(
      <div className="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        className={classes.button + " "}
      >
        Default
      </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Now you only need to change the styling of the button (remove / modify this):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    margin: theme.spacing(1)
  }
}));
```

If you want you can add padding / margin to your button. NEVER EVER add padding / margin to classes like `.row` or `.col-*`

Comment: This works perfectly, now it makes sense why in some places in my program this problem hadn't occur, so i should i always use div with col and use padding and margin in the components, thx!!

Comment: I was just refactoring my code to make sure the rules you mentioned are applied, and i noticed that in one part i was giving a `Select` the class grid size `col-md-12`, and this `Select` was inside a `div` with the actual grid size, for example `col-md-3`, now the reason i had given the size 12 is because i want the `Select` to be in full size!!, i tried replacing it with a width:100% in the style, but it doesn't work, so is this okay using grid size 12 to make a component full size?, didn't you say to give this grid class to the `div`s only ?

Comment: Width: 100% should work. I could not imagine why not. There's probably something wrong with your css but I would use col-* only as wrappers

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it into `Div`

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    buttonArray.push(
      <Div className="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        className={classes.button}
      >
        Default
      </Button></Div>
    );
  }
```

you need to import Div before use it.

```
import Div from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-grid-testcase-efi4u

Comment: Yours doens't work as it should, when i resize the window and make it bigger, more then 4 button falls in one row

Comment: Oh, sry i hand't, yes the updated code works perfectly, thx!, i will consider this as the alternative solution, by the way, is there any merit to this imported `Div` and the normal `div`?

Comment: nope. just the same but Div is from component will have more advantage.